# Unable to Export From Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, export

I'm having an issue trying to export pngs from Illustrator. I have added them to my asset export, but when attempting the export I get the following error:

Unable to export the following files:

Then it lists the files it cannot export.[image]

Comment: With such an uninformative error message, I don't know how anyone could assist you.

Comment: I agree, Adobe should make more intuitive messages. I suspect that this has to do with the items having a clipping mask.

Comment: Either the images dont exist or the files are locked (like used by another process)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide enough info, so I can only guess:
If those PNG(s) are not embedded in your drawing, make them so.
That may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try Export As or Save As just to see if you'll get a more specific error. This happened to me and when I tried Save AS > PDF I got "Objects land out of document bounds".

To resolve, I had to start a new document and I added more large artboards until Illustrator switched to "Large sized canvas" mode.

https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/kb/large-sized-canvas-troubleshooting.html